# Elegir algo de forma aleatoria respetando sus probabilidades

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Tengo una aplicación web donde hay participantes que se almacenan en una base de datos, cada uno tiene unas probabilidades diferentes (1 - 10). Debo elegir al ganador (1 o varios) teniendo más probabilidades el que tenga un número mayor.

Para que se entienda mejor, estos números son asignados en base a la cantidad de tareas que ha realizado para participar y puede haber varios ganadores.

No se me ocurre nada, ni por donde comenzar.

Comment: Una manera de hacerlo sería generar una consulta que te devuelva una tabla con 1 entrada por fila(salvo que ya la guardes de esta manera), después deberías simplemente hacer una selección aleatoria sobre esa tabla, de esta manera respetarías las probabilidades y tendrías un ganador aleatorio

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar un random con posibilidad hay dos opciones:

A: La primera, no te la recomiendo, es poner en un array cada usuario tantas veces como posibilidades tenga y elegir un elemento random del array.

B: La segunda, más interesante para ti, se trata de la técnica accept/reject. See realiza en dos pasos: 1) eliges un elemento random 2) lo aceptas o lo descartas, imagina que para ese usuario tienes una posibilidad de 2 entre 10, pues lanzas el 'dado' (de 10 caras) y si sale 2 o inferior lo aceptas, en caso contrario, lo descartas i vas de nuevo al paso 1).

Perfectamente explicado en el minuto 15 del vídeo: [Genetic algorithm , Pool selection](https://youtu.be/816ayuhDo0E)

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla seria, traer todos los elementos de la tabla y meterlos en un array, con la cantidad de elementos que registraste en la tabla tenemos el universo que compone tu array, ahora solo usamos un random.

$posicionDeGanador = rand(0, $cantidadDeRegistros);
$ganador=$ArrayDeAlumnos[$posicionDeGanador];

$cantidadDeRegistros, son los elementos que metiste al array.

Para saber que posibilidad tenia de ganar cada uno puedes usar algo como:

$valores = array_count_values($ArrayDeAlumnos);

Para mas información.
[más información](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-count-values.php)